# Looking for a better way to present a page that uses checkboxes to select from a dropdown

Tags: forms, gui-design

I inherited a web app and have been slowly bringing it up to more modern standards. This page in particular has really got me stumped. I don't know how to best present this in a better more functional way. Does anyone have any ideas that I could turn into something?

It's basically to send email messages to employees. They can select a department which in turn will select those employees in that department in the multi-select box. Or they can just pick and choose from the select box alone. The message box is CKeditor, an old version which I will update.

Here is the page. All names are fictitious.
[image: horrible form]

Comment: It might help if you defined your the problem with the existing method. Beyond not look particularly engaging, what is wrong with what you already have? In what way does it not work for your users? Beware of change for the sake of change.

Comment: Off-topic WTF? There is no site review. This is a UX forum and I am trying to get help on UX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a pretty good case for **a standard "To:" field that accepts both names and departments**.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBTIkm.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The <kbd>Address Book...</kbd> button could open a modal that contains a searchable list of addresses that shows the information currently displayed in your select box.

Additionally, a typeahead feature could be useful to avoid having to open the Address Book at all... If you type "`Ale`", then "`Alex Glow (Server)`" shows as a suggestion to add. There are a number of plugins that are designed to provide exactly this functionality.